# Windows only java Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: java, linux, windows, macos

I have looked at the other UnsatisfiedLinkError questions, and my question seems to be different.

I have made jar files for Mac OS X, Linux, and Windows from the same code (with OS specific code added.)
When I run them, they all work. If I give them to someone else, The OS X and Linux jars run for them, but in Windows it dies with:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\cygwin64\tmp\myDll2681353484644451507.dll: Can't find dependent libraries
>          at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
>   etc.

The dll is there in tmp, and permissions in Windows seem to be okay.

I'm open to suggestions.

UPDATE: I added an account to my Windows Computer on which the jar files already work when using my account, and that new account gets exactly the same message as those other people get.

Sorry for the delay in replying, I've been trying a number of things.

Thanks,

John

Comment: Sounds like the myDll2681353484644451507.dll depends on another dll which cannot be found in library path. 

Do you unpack all of your dlls?

Comment: Do you depend on cygwin? Maybe you need to install something else within cygwin.